# How to set different font size for text of label nodes in gexf format

Tags: gephi

I'm having a problem with label size. I need my graph to show text of node labels with different font sizes.

This is not work:

```
<node id="155" label="text text" font-size="10000px">
    viz:color r="0" g="255" b="0"/>
</node>
```

And this make another size for node and not for text of label:

```
<node id="155" label="text text">
    <viz:color r="0" g="255" b="0"/>
    <viz:size value="17"/>
</node>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify node label font sizes in gexf. This is not covered by the [specification](https://gephi.org/gexf/1.2draft/gexf-12draft-primer.pdf). Perhaps the reason is that you can modify this from within Gephi to match your preferences